# Hexo deploy always deletes all my previous commits

Tags: git, github, github-pages, hexo

I'm wondering the proper steps of using Hexo to publish a post to my Github Pages. Based on [tutorial](https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html), it looks super simple and straightforward, but it's causing big headache and pain for me.

Here are my steps that I followed:

`hexo new post "my new post"`

`hexo generate`

`hexo deploy` (this is the disaster command)

After hexo deploy, all my previous commits will be deleted away on my Github pages, what did I do wrong? Please help.

I've contacted GitHub human support, they looked up my Git push history and told me that I'm force pushing the commits which ends up deleting all my previous commits.
I'm never aware of this `force` push. What goes wrong?

Then I did extensive research and tried another way, I simply followed this official [tutorial](https://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html). What I do is:

`hexo new post "my new post"`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "commit message"`

`git push`

But my personal website doesn't show my new posts at all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the output of git status 1) after git add and 2) after git commit?  Can you verify what your oriin is set to using the git remote -v command? I believe git push will automatically default to origin if it is set

Comment: Thanks @jbu, git status all looks normal to me. git remote -v also returns me correct result: ``origin https://github.com/fishercoder1534/fishercoder1534.github.io.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/fishercoder1534/fishercoder1534.github.io.git (push)``

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your project's main Git repository is separate from your deployment username.github.io repository. When you `hexo deploy` to your username.github.io account it will simply push all changes with a commit message of the date/time of your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relies on your deploy configuration which is in the `_config.yml` file.

> After hexo deploy, all my previous commits will be deleted away on my Github pages, what did I do wrong?

Based on your description, I think you have used git to have version controlled your hexo project repo which is generated by `hexo init fishercoder1534.github.io`. And then you have also set it's origin to be https://github.com/fishercoder1534/fishercoder1534.gi‌​thub.io.git. It should be noted that, when you use `git init` to set up git, it creates **master** as your default branch.

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/fighter3228/fishercoder1534.github.io.git
  branch: master
  message: "Site updated: {{ now('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') }}"
```

Base on your description again, I think your deploy configuration in the `_config.yml` file should look like above. The problem is that when you use git in the same repo again as a deploy tool. And what's worse, it uses the same branch **master** as you used in order to version control your project repo. That's why all your previous commits have been deleted.

### How to solve it quickly

If you still have your hexo project repo locally, to have all your commits back, you can just do `git push -f` in your hexo project repo, then you can see at Github, all your commits are back.

Then if you want use git as a deploy tool and you don't want create another repo for your github page, you can just modify your deploy configuration as follows:

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: https://github.com/fighter3228/fishercoder1534.github.io.git
  branch: gh-pages
  message: "Site updated: {{ now('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') }}"
```

Run 'hexo g -d' to let hexo create **gh-pages** branch for the deployment. Then github will automatically build your github pages from **gh-pages** branch while in the same time you can keep your hexo project repo version controlled at master branch.

### To better solve this problem

I suggest you to create another repo at Github, one repo to version control your hexo project folder and have another repo to deploy your github pages.